# Compiling a deodexed AOSP?

Tags: android, android-source

I'm trying to compile a deodexed aosp for my GSM Galaxy Nexus (maguro). I searched on Google, with no result. It seems that there is no flag which allow to compile a deodexed system.

However in the makefile build/core/main.mk I found this:

```
   ## precise GC ##

ifneq ($(filter dalvik.gc.type-precise,$(PRODUCT_TAGS)),)
  # Enabling type-precise GC results in larger optimized DEX files.  The
  # additional storage requirements for ".odex" files can cause /system
  # to overflow on some devices, so this is configured separately for
  # each product.
  ADDITIONAL_BUILD_PROPERTIES += dalvik.vm.dexopt-flags=m=y
endif
```

Any idea? thanks

Comment: Are you trying to compile whole Android OS, or is it only some particular system jars you're looking for? In latter case there are unobfuscated and undexed jars found under out -dir somewhere (can't remember exact location).

Comment: I'd like to build the entire system deodexed

Answer (score 11):

To actually get a deodexed build, I had to define those:

```
export DISABLE_DEXPREOPT=true
export WITH_DEXPREOPT=false
```

Then 'make clean'.

Alternatively I tried also this:

```
make DISABLE_DEXPREOPT=true WITH_DEXPREOPT=false -j8 otapackage
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [backsmali](https://code.google.com/p/smali/wiki/DeodexInstructions) which can combine odex and apk  files

```
baksmali -a [api_level] -x [odex_file] -d [framework_dir]
```

Or change the WITH_DEXPREOPT environment variable in

```
build/target/board/generic/BoardConfig.mk
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write a shell script that makes use of [smali](http://code.google.com/p/smali/) (or xUltimate if on Windows).